# Android, how to set meta data to MP4 file?

Tags: android, metadata, media, mp4

I would like to set meta data to MP4 file.

I create MP4 file via:

```
new MediaMuxer(mPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
```

and file has meta:

```
Title:   unknown
Artist:  unknown
Album:   unknown
Comment:
...
```

similar as: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GILkM.png)

I found that for API21+ i could make metadata via: `MediaMetadata.Builder` but how could i save metadata to created MP4 file?

Without extern library please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit/write metadata, Android SDK doesn´t have any method, probably by copyright issues, but you can use options like:

https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser

http://multimedia.cx/eggs/supplying-ffmpeg-with-metadata/

Probably this is what you are looking for (using FFmpeg):
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameRecorder.java

Comment: What about this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer#metadata-track ? Isn't it for writing and reading the metadata? Sadly I've failed to understand how to use it, but it seems promising... Could you please check it out and publish about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36473337/878126 ?

Comment: You told that SDK doesn't allow this probably by copyright issues, but what if I would like to save `.mp4` file that I got as video from my camera on Android phone? There is should not be any copyright issues...